# phantomjs custom header in robot framework

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, robotframework

We are using phantomjs browser in robot script and have a requirement to set the phantomjs custom header as a part of capability. Below is the code snippet we have tried

```
${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Authorization=Basic <Credentials>
    ${service args}=    Create List    --proxy=localhost:8080    --web-security=false   --ignore-ssl-errors=yes    --ssl-protocol=ANY    --load-images=yes
    Create Webdriver    PhantomJS   service_args=${service args}    executable_path=/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/s4c/WEB-INF/classes/WebDriver/phantomjs    desired_capabilitie=${dc}
```

This is code is failing to launch the browser. We didn't find concrete documentation for setting capability to phantomjs in robot. If anyone tried setting custom header to phantomjs in robot framework please suggest us.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for picking PhantomJS over the headless Chrome or Firefox? At present it is deprecated in Selenium and to be removed in the upcoming version.

Comment: @A.Kootstra : We are running the test scripts in server which doesn't allow any software installation. As we know in order to run chrome in headless mode, chrome must be installed in the system and hence we are going with phantomjs which is completely portable headless browser

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps stating the obvious: none of your end users are using the system under test with PhantomJS which significantly lowers confidence of the achieved results. So for that reason I strongly suggest putting effort in getting the right environment setup so that the test mimic end user situation as close as possible.

It is very likely that you're using a modern version of Selenium that no longer supports PhantomJS as it is Deprecated as of Selenium 3.6.0 and *removed* as of 3.7.0. [Releases](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases).

So if your `pip list` shows a Selenium Module version of `3.6.0` or higher you may want to downgrade.